# htaccess redirecting previous URLs to single URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

After deploying a new site, I'm working to redirect old urls to a single page. Trying both redirects and rewrites. Desired:

```
/oldurl/page1 => /newurl
/oldurl/page2 => /newurl
```

The following redirect works, but not entirely. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /oldurl /newurl
```

Becomes the following, where `page1` should actually be removed

```
/newurl/page1
```

The following rewrite doesn't rewrite at all:

```
RewriteRule ^oldurl/(.*)$ /newurl [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` for this to get more control via regex patterns:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldurl(/.*)?$ /newurl
```